# VsCode - Clear i18nAlly

Tags: visual-studio-code, i18n-ally

After removing i18n-ally plugin in VsCode, it keeps modifying my `.vscode/setting.json` as below

```
  "i18n-ally.localesPaths": [
    ...,
    "ios/Pods/boost/boost/locale",
    "ios/Pods/RCT-Folly/folly/lang",
    "ios/Pods/boost/boost/predef/language",
    ...
  ]
```

Even I discard the changes in Source tree, it keeps changing my file.
How to stop it from modifying the `setting.json`?

Comment: 1) Does it do this even if you reload / close&reopen VS Code? 2) What if you delete the corresponding directory under `~/.vscode/extensions`?

Comment: @user
1) yes
2) no corresponding directory under `~/.vscode/extensions` after I delete the extension